# How to make ready APK file for publish means export? and what are the parameter to set?

Tags: android, export, publish

I have made a small application in android and I want to publish it on market.

So first of all how to export final APK from eclipse and
second what are the parameters to set in AndroidManifest file?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) Extracting signed package

A quote from [here](http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-development/1837-issue-signing-app-eclipse.html):

> Compiling and signing with Eclipse ADT
>   When using Eclipse with ADT, you can
>   use the Export Wizard to export a
>   signed .apk (and even create a new
>   keystore, if necessary). The Export
>   Wizard performs all the interaction
>   with the Keytool and Jarsigner for
>   you, which allows you to perform
>   signing via a graphical interface
>   instead of the command-line. Because
>   the Export Wizard uses both Keytool
>   and Jarsigner, you should ensure that
>   they are accessible on your computer,
>   as described above in the Basic Setup
>   for Signing.
>
> To create a signed .apk, right-click
>   the project in the Package Explorer
>   and select Android Tools > Export
>   Signed Application Package.
>   (Alternatively, open your
>   AndroidManifest.xml file in Eclipse,
>   open the Overview tab, and click Use
>   the Export Wizard.) The window that
>   appears will display any errors found
>   while attempting to export your
>   application. If no errors are found,
>   continue with the Export Wizard, which
>   will guide you through the process of
>   signing your application, including
>   steps for selecting the private key
>   with which to sign the .apk, or
>   creating a new keystore and private
>   key.
>
> When you complete the Export Wizard,
>   you'll have a signed .apk that's ready
>   for distribution.

2) Manifest 
There are a lot of params in manifest file. The main ones you need is:
    Parameters of manifest tag:

```
package="com.yourcompany.yourapppackage"
```

is the package name of your project. I assume you already have it.

```
android:versionCode="4" android:versionName="1.0.3"
```

These two describes the code and name of the version of your software. version code should be always an integer, and version name can be any string you like. Don't forget to increase your version code, when uploading an update.

Nested tag `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />`
is a tag, which specifies the minimum api level your application uses.

Nested tags `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` are necessary only if you need some permissions for application.

Read more about manifest file [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).